# parse error on input ‘::’ when making an explicit type definition for a function which accepts multiple arguments

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci

I am working on a project in Haskell for the first time and I am working on translating over my ADT into the code properly, however when I am writing the explicit type definitions for my functions and I load my code in GHCi I get the following error:

> Blockquote parse error on input ‘::’

The line in question is for a function called  type which accepts a character and a tuple and returns a tuple as shown below:

```
type :: validChars -> tuple -> tuple
```

where `validChars` is the list of valid characters, the definitions for my lists are shown here if this helps:

```
tuple = (l, r, b, k)
l = [l | l <- validChars]
m = [m | m <- validChars]
b = [b | b <- validChars]
k = [k | k <- validChars]
validChars = [ chr c | c <-alphanumericChars , c >= 32, c <= 122]
alphanumericChars = [ a | a <- [0..255]]
```

I checked to make sure it wasn't `validChars` causing the error by replacing it with the `Chars`type as shown:

```
type :: Chars -> tuple -> tuple
```

But I still get the same error, I am a complete beginner at Haskell so I'm probably missing something important, but I  am not sure what that would be exactly; I've looked at answers for similar questions I have been unsuccessful thus far. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: `type` is [a keyword](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#type).  Your types also need to start with [Capital Letters](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations)

Comment: I feel so stupid for not checking this, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` is a keyword in Haskell, so you can't use it as the name of your function.

Furthermore type names start with a capital letter in Haskell and anything starting with a lower case letter in a type is a type variable. So if you define `myFunction :: validChars -> tuple -> tuple`, that defines a function that takes two arguments of arbitrary types and produces a result of the same type as the second argument. It's the same as `myFunction :: a -> b -> b`.

If you write `myFunction :: Chars -> tuple -> tuple`, you get a function whose first argument needs to be of type `Chars` (which needs to exist) and the second argument is of an arbitrary type that is also the type of the result. Again it's the same as `myFunction :: Chars -> a -> a`.

Note that for this to work, you'll actually have to have defined a type named `Chars` somewhere. If you want to take a list of `Char`s, the type should be `[Char]` instead.

And if you want the second argument and result to actually be tuples (rather than just a type variable arbitrarily named `tuple`), you need to specify a tuple type like `(a,b,c,d)`, which would accept arbitrary 4-tuples, or something specific like `(Integer, String, String, String)`, which would accept 4-tuples containing an `Integer` and three `String`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this comment is really helpful, I should have checked the keywords before starting, ah well the more you know!